# Removing a hash element if its value is "undef"

Tags: perl, hash

I have seen `delete` that deletes a hash element. But what if some of the elements dates have `undef` for a value?

I would like to delete all hash elements whose value is `undef`.

How would I do that in a single line, or the simplest way.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Where did it go wrong?  Show your best attempt and we can help you fix what's wrong with it.  Also note that entire Perl programs can be written in "a single line", since Perl doesn't care about whitespace.  Did you mean "a single statement"?

Comment: From a hash reference, `$hash`, the one liner would be `map {delete $hash->{$_} unless defined $hash->{$_}} keys %{$hash};`

Comment: `delete $hash{$_} for grep { defined $hash{$_} } keys %hash; `

Comment: Hint for future development: I always make sure my keys are defined before I save them.

Comment: @eballes: It's frowned upon to use `map` in void context like that. `map` is for translating one list into another. If you need a simple iterator you should use `for`. Your statement is exactly equivalent to `delete $hash->{$_} unless defined $hash->{$_} for keys %{$hash}`

Comment: As an alternative though - if undef keys are a a problem, you can use `//` to 'default', which may be useful in certain scenarios. E.g. `print "$key => ", $hash{$key} // 'ERRORVALUE', "\n"; `

Comment: @Sobrique: I get what you're saying, but I think I prefer a simple `defined` test over `ne 'ERRORVALUE'`. As Bulrush says above, most often the elements with undefined values shouldn't have got into the hash in the first place, although I can imagine a number of situations where it could be useful to break that rule

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that you delete a hash slice, using `grep` to determine which keys correspond to an undefined value

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %h = (
    a => 1,
    b => undef,
    c => 1,
    d => undef,
);

delete @h{ grep { not defined $h{$_} } keys %h };

use Data::Dump;
dd \%h;
```

#### output

```
{ a => 1, c => 1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (keys %hash) {
    delete $hash->{$_} unless defined $hash->{$_};
}
```

Comment: Needs a `defined`. Because otherwise you'll delete `''` and `0`.

Comment: You need $hash->{$_}  instead of $hash{$_}. I tried to edit the post, but stack overflow needs 6 chars, and I had only 4 chars to improve.